# Remove all characters after specific string in one column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the column PDF_texts contains one long string of text extracted from PDFs. Each row represents a different PDF file.

I want to look through the  PDF_texts column, and for each column only keep the characters that appear after the words 'NOTICE OF COUNCIL MEMBERS MOTIONS' or 'Motions on Notice' , and before the words 'NEW BUSINESS' or 'New Business'

As a first step I took out everything before NOTICE OF COUNCIL MEMBERS MOTIONS:

```
df['PDF_text'] = df['PDF_text'].str.replace(r"^.+?(?=NOTICE OF COUNCIL MEMBERS MOTIONS)", "")
```

Questions:

1. Is there anyway to combine this with an OR statement to remove any text before NOTICE OF COUNCIL MEMBERS MOTIONS **or** Motions on Notice
2. How would I alter this code to then take out anything **after** and including the words 'New Business' (no matter whether caps or not)?

Any help appreciated! edited because I realised that my first solution wasn't doing exactly what I wanted..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.extract`:

```
>>> df["PDF_text"].str.extract(r'(?<=NOTICE OF COUNCIL MEMBERS MOTIONS)(.*?)(?=New Business)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

`(?<=...)` matches at the location that was preceded by the first string (NOTICE OF COUNCIL MEMBERS MOTIONS).

`(?=...)` matches at the location that is followed by second string (New business).

`.*` matches everything in beween.

Comment: Thank you!!! Is there anyway to combine NOTICE OF COUNCIL MEMBERS MOTIONS with an OR statement, so that it deletes anything before `NOTICE OF COUNCIL MEMBERS MOTIONS` *or* `Motions on Notice`

Comment: I would do it in two steps because `re` look behinds need to be fixed width.

Comment: @mobo1 - Maybe replace "motions on notice" with "notice of council members motions" and then use the regex above. That would be a workaround.